# How can I make a selective hover in Vue Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hover, frontend

I want a hover button to only style the nested elements inside it.
Currently in my code hovering over a single button will style the nested elements inside all its sibling buttons.

Any suggestions?

```
<div id="app">
  <button
   v-on:mouseover="isHovering = true"
   v-on:mouseout="isHovering = false">Button 1
  </button>
    <p v-bind:class="{hovering: isHovering}">
    {{ isHovering ? "Yes" : "No" }}
    </p>
  <button
    v-on:mouseover="isHovering = true"
    v-on:mouseout="isHovering = false">Button 2
  </button>
    <p v-bind:class="{hovering: isHovering}">
    {{ isHovering ? "Yes" : "No" }}
    </p>
</div>
```

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    isHovering: false
  }
})
```

```
.hovering {
  display: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current code you only have 1 data property "isHovering", and both of your `<p>` elements use it to conditionally use the .hovering {display: red}.

You could create another data property for your second button. If you are going to have a lot of buttons trying to do this, your code will get out of hand quite quickly.

```
<button
  v-on:mouseover="isSecondButtonHovering = true"
  v-on:mouseout="isSecondButtonHovering = false">Button 2
</button>
<p :class="{hovering: isSecondButtonHovering}">
  {{ isSecondButtonHovering ? "Yes" : "No" }}
</p>
```

Comment: This was my first instinct, but I decided not to do it because it's a shortcut and not scaleable code!

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned with styling, you can succeed with pure css using the [:hover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) selector.

Example for your use case:

```css
button:hover + p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

> I want a hover button to only style the nested elements inside it.

This is not true, your `p` tags are not inside your `button` tags (even though you indented your code as such).